# backbone's delegateEvents issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have this situation with backbone:

```
events: {
    'click': 'test1',
    'click .modify': 'test2'
}
```

When I click on .modify is fired both test1 and test2.
How to solve?

http://jsfiddle.net/keepyourweb/VU8pE/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have thought that `e.preventDefault()` would have worked too...

But, I found that `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` does the trick for you.

My guess is that both event callbacks have been queued by this point which is why `preventDefault` didn't work.

Thanks for the jsFiddle.  It really helped!

Answer (score 0):

The first click event is being attached to `el` so any clicks to `.modify` will bubble up to `test1` as well.

If you really want to do this then set up your event handlers like this:

```
test1: function(e) {},

test2: function(e) {
    // this will stop "test1"
    // from being called
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I tried but does not work.
However I added the link To jsfiddle.